# NSBundle pathForResource is nil,how can I get the path?

Tags: ios, objective-c, null, nsbundle

I put pictures in the supporting files,why I get the nil by NSBundle mainbudle?Should I put these pictures in which folder?Or I make other error?

code:

```
- (void)startAnimating:(int)count andPictureName:(NSString *)picName {

    if (self.imgViewCat.isAnimating) {
        return;
    }


    NSMutableArray *arrayM = [NSMutableArray array];

    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        NSString *imgName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@_%02d.jpg", picName,i];
        //The first method UIImage *imgCat = [UIImage imageNamed:imgName];
        //The second method 
        NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:imgName ofType:nil];
        NSLog(@"%@",path);
        UIImage *imgCat = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:path];
        [arrayM addObject:imgCat];

    }
}
```

PS:The first method,I use //UIImage *imgCat = [UIImage imageNamed:imgName]; It does work.But I want to use the second method.Because NSBundle mainBundle can manage the memory,release the memory.But the first method is strong,it will keep memory.

**The solution**:resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:imgName

Comment: try this NSString * path =[[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:imgName];

Comment: Hi. Why do you want have images in the main bundle? The simplest way is put images in the `*.xcassets` folder and later get them via `[UIImage imageNamed:<image_name>]`.

Comment: Run this in the simulator. Log `[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath]`. Log `imgName`. Look at the resulting path. Is it what you meant? Is there actually a file at that location on your Mac?

Comment: The first method,I use //UIImage *imgCat = [UIImage imageNamed:imgName]; It does work.But I want to use the second method.Because NSBundle mainBundle can manage the memory

Answer (score -1):

you can get the NSBundle in 2 ways

**SWIFT**

1. Get the bundle by class

   ```
   let bundle = NSBundle(forClass: YourClass.self)
   ```
2. You can get the bundle by identifier

   ```
   NSBundle(identifier: "bundleID")
   ```

The problem with the first is that you might want to use the the image assets from another bundle, and you cant access it, for example you will not import a submodule in your class only to get YourClass.self

The second solution will help you with that but the problem is that its tricky to get the bundle id, for that i created a small class called Configuration

```
internal class Configuration {

/// The current framework bundle
internal static let bundle = NSBundle(forClass: Configuration.self)

/// The framework identifier
internal static let identifier: String = {
    guard let identifier = Configuration.bundle.bundleIdentifier else {
        fatalError("Missing bundle identifier.")
    }
    return identifier
}()
}
```

And you can get the image like this

```
let bundle = NSBundle(forClass: YourClass.self) //Or NSBundle(identifier: Configuration.identifier)
let image = UIImage(named: "MyImage", inBundle: bundle, compatibleWithTraitCollection: nil)
```